# ASP.NET Core2 - Policy Based Azure AD security

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to implement Policy based permissions using the reference here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt826337.aspx

This is a new .NetCore2 project and I have no idea what the error means.  I have tried adding .AddTransient or .AddScoped to no avail.

Startup Configuration Section

```
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AtLeast3Years",
              policy => policy
                .Requirements
                .Add(new ExperienceRequirement(3)));
        });

        services.AddSession();

        services.AddEditor();

        services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationHandler, ExperienceHandler>();
```

Requirement

```
public class ExperienceRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public int Years { get; private set; }

    public ExperienceRequirement(int minimumYears)
    {
        Years = minimumYears;
    }
}
```

Handler

```
public class ExperienceHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ExperienceRequirement>
{

protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
      AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
      ExperienceRequirement requirement)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Error

'ConsumerWebCore.Filters.ExperienceHandler' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddSingleton(IServiceCollection)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ConsumerWebCore.Filters.ExperienceHandler' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationHandler'.  ConsumerWebCore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to register it as an IAuthorizationHandler.

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ExperienceHandler>();
```

It's an authorization handler, not an authentication handler.

Comment: Thx Juunas, you are a star, you have no idea how many hours I have wasted on this.